# Pattern for geolocation

Tags: lists, ios, maps, geolocation

I need to design geolocation in an app. This app allows to search in two ways: textual search, by inserting the address; or geolocation search, knowing the user's position and showing it in a map.

I have a screen with two tabs - map and list. At the bottom of both screens there is a button which allows to activate the geolocation. I put this button in both screens because the same results that could be seen in the map could be seen in a list view, so I think that isn't correct put the geolocation button only in the map view.

My problem is that when performing user testing several people don't notice the button, and when I ask them to activate geolocation they spend some times looking around for the button.

Maybe I have to move this button in the top of my UI, but I'm not sure because I don't want to clutter the display, so I ask you some advices. 
Thanks to all.

I upload the img of the interface which I'm talking about for better clarity.
The labels are in italian, however I hope you'll understand.

[image: search type]

[image: list view]

[image: map view]

Comment: I must be one of the test users myself - where is the geolocation button? Is it that banner at the very bottom of the pages? Because if so then it doesn't look like a button at all, but a label.

Comment: Don't consider visual aspect. This is only a mockup. Neither the Filter button looks like a button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the main problem with the current design is the visual separation between the textual search option and the geolocation option. You are giving the user a choice between these two search methods but not presenting them together in the same place. The text search option is displayed prominently at the top and is easy to recognise but the geolocation option is hidden away in the footer, after the results are displayed.

Consider instead these examples where the two search methods are presented in close proximity:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes you right, but before the screens I uploaded, there is another screen which allows user to choose the type of search (textual or geoloc.). The problem is where to put the geoloc. option in search results screen. See the new screen on my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend putting it on top-right or top-left.

How about those components in an overlay?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes in the map view it could works but in the list-view?An overlay in the list view could lead some visualization problems (because under the search layer there are the restaurant info with plain text and this could make it difficult to read).

Comment: How about a on-demand collapsible overlay which slides-in from either left or right?

Comment: See updated answer